# The difference between declaring a name, introducing a name, and declaring an entity

Tags: c++, entity, declaration, language-lawyer, using-declaration

From the C++11 standard, §7.3.3[namespace.udecl]/1:

> A using-declaration introduces a name into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.
>
> > *using-declaration*:
> >
> > > `using typename`<sub>*opt*</sub> *nested-name-specifier unqualified-id* `;`
> > >         `using ::` *unqualified-id* `;`
>
> **The member name specified in a using-declaration is declared in the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.**

What do they mean by the name being declared in the declarative region where the using-declaration occurs?

Does this mean the same as introducing that name into the declarative region where the using-declaration occurs?

Also is there a difference between declaring a name and declaring the entity that the name denotes?

Example:

```
namespace N { static int i = 1; } /* Declares an entity denoted by 
    the name i in the declarative region of the namespace N. 
    Introduces the name into the declarative region of the namespace N.
    Declares the name i in the declarative region of the namespace N? */
using N::i; /* Declares the name i in the declarative region of the
    global namespace. Also introduces that name into the declarative
    region of the global namespace? Also declares the entity that the
    name i denotes? */
```

Comment: Now that I'm answering your third question on this topic, I think I'm finally understanding this!

Comment: @Barry I'm patiently waiting for Supremum's exploration of the standard to touch Clause 14. Ah, what a barrage of questions and bug reports that will be! :-)

Comment: @Supremum I hope you're not taking the comment above the wrong way - it's friendly banter. You're raising interesting issues, some of them not obvious at all. Keep asking!

Comment: So far: 10 non-rejected bugs in clang (3 fixed) and 13 non-rejected bugs in gcc (8 confirmed, 0 fixed). So far I have mostly looked in chapter 3 and 7 :P

Comment: Thanks for the help Barry. I'm much less confused now. I realised however that the c++ standard can't be 100 % precise in its terms, and I shouldn't take everything too literally. Its good to understand the terms used, but there is a limit in the precision of them. I should probably focus more on making my own mental model of the c++ standard. That is usually how I learn things, explaining it in my own terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From first principles, an *entity* is, from [basic]

> a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template
>   specialization, namespace, parameter pack, or `this`. [...] Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a declaration.

Declarations declare things. To be declared means that it was introduced by a declaration, from [basic.scope.declarative]

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a *declarative region*, which is the largest part
>   of the program in which that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name
>   to refer to the same entity.
>
> The names declared by a declaration are introduced into the scope in which the declaration occurs, except
>   that the presence of a `friend` specifier (11.3), certain uses of the *elaborated-type-specifier* (7.1.6.3), and
>   *using-directives* (7.3.4) alter this general behavior.

None of those exceptions are relevant here, since we're talking about *using-declarations* and not *using-directives*. Let me alter your example somewhat so as to avoid the global namespace:

```
namespace N {        //  + declarative region #1
                     //  |
    static int i;    //  | introduces a name into this region
                     //  | this declaration introduces an entity
}                    //  +
```

So to start with, `N::i` is an entity that is declared in namespace `N` and introduced into the scope of `N`. Now, let's add a *using-declaration*:

```
namespace B {        //  + declarative region #2
                     //  |
    using N::i;      //  | declaration introduces a name i
                     //  | but this is not an entity
}                    //  +
```

From [namespace.udecl], we have:

> If a *using-declaration* names a constructor (3.4.3.1), it implicitly declares a set of constructors in the
>   class in which the using-declaration appears (12.9); otherwise the name specified in a *using-declaration* is a
>   **synonym** for a set of declarations in another namespace or class.

The *using-declaration* `using N::i` does not name a constructor, so rather than having the name `i` be a new entity, it is instead a *synonym* for `N::i`.

So basically, both `i`s are names introduced in and declared in their respective namespaces. In `N`, `i` declares an entity with static linkage, but in `B`, `i` declares a synonym to that entity - not a new entity.

Comment: just a side-comment: are there any names that don't denote an entity?

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes. A name can denote a label.

Comment: ah, yes, with `goto`, no wonder it didn't pop up in my mind immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

> What do they mean by the name being declared in the declarative region
>   where the using-declaration occurs?

I'll try and answer this with an example of my understanding of it (Refer to my comments in the depicted code):

```
// "namespace X {}" introduces a declarative region of the namespace X
namespace X {
  //The name SomeObject is now introduced into the declarative region X
  // It is only visible in that declarative region
  using Y::SomeObject;
}//Declarative region X ENDS here
// SomeObject NOT visible here
```

Below is an example where the (compiler) error makes it clear where the name is not visible:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
  struct X{};
}

namespace B
{
  struct X{};
}

namespace C
{
  using A::X;

  void foo(X){}
}

namespace D
{
  using B::X;

  void foo(X){}
}

void foo(X){} //FAILS TO COMPILE - DELIBERATE!!!

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```