# Rules regarding using declarations c++

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, language-lawyer, using-declaration

After reading the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493734/local-extern-variable-declaration-with-using-directive-in-the-nearest-enclosing), I thought I understood why the program failed, since the using directive [does not actually declare the entity `i` in the region](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives). However names introduced by a using declaration [can be used just like any other name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) and [acts like a declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708705/the-difference-between-declaring-a-name-introducing-a-name-and-declaring-an-en/31710257).

With GCC, this fails

```
#include <iostream>


namespace X { int i = 1; }

using X::i;

int main() {
    extern int i;
    i = 2;
    std::cout<<i;
}
```

But this is accepted

```
#include <iostream>

int i;

int main() {
    extern int i;
    i = 2;
    std::cout<<i;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. MSVC accepts the first but clang-cl doesn't.

Comment: Just FYI - I didn't downvote. I was just adding a bit of extra info for others.

Comment: @AdrianMole Sorry I was not accusing you, I just didn't know were else to add that. I would appreciate constructive criticism if you have it though. 2 down votes in about 10 minutes without much explanation is a bit frustrating.

Comment: NP. The DVs are as much a mystery to me as they are to you. But votes are anonymous on SO, and asking for explanations is generally futile.

Comment: @AdrianMole *Sigh* and once the question has two downvotes, no one is going to look at it so not only do I lose what little reputation I have, without much explanation, I probably won't get any more information as well. It can be frustrating asking questions here sometimes, I put in a lot of effort to be specific, cite other sources/questions and provide examples. I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: The question is good. You got my +1. It may get even better if you move the intro to the end somehow, as the question is quite clear from the code itself while the intro is a bit vague till you get to the code. Nevertheless, the question is totally legit and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the example you've given *does* compile, but it fails to *link*. The issue is the line

```
extern int i;
```

What you're telling the compiler/linker here is "there will be a variable `i` defined somewhere else in the program, so, compiler, don't worry if you can't find the definition. Linker, I expect you to find the definition of `i` once you have all of the object files and link that in here."

We can see this in action using compiler explorer:

[Without the extern declaration](https://godbolt.org/z/fbhcT5)

[With the extern declaration](https://godbolt.org/z/9114ds)

In the second case, the declaration of `i` "shadows" the `X::i` which is visible at global scope, so we get the instruction

```
mov     DWORD PTR i[rip], 2
```

whereas without the extern declaration, we get

```
mov     DWORD PTR X::i[rip], 2
```

though I'm not totally sure on the shadowing part, as neither gcc nor clang warns about that with `-Wshadow`. In any case, we see now why the second example fails to link: the linker is trying to find the definition of `i` to use here, and while `X::i` is defined at global scope, `i` is not.